# How to split string and store value as dictionary with predifined keys

Tags: python

With the string variable being:

```
text = 'red~5~cat'
```

I would like to split it by '~' character and store the values as a dictionary. I have reserved the names for the keys and they are:

```
key_names = ['color', 'number', 'pet']
```

I wonder if there is a way to pack the result of splitting as a dictionary below?

```
{'color':'red', 'number':5, 'pet':'cat'}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about simply zipping your keys with the result of split, as follows

```
>>> dict(zip(key_names, text.split('~'))
{'pet': 'cat', 'number': '5', 'color': 'red'}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function:

```
>>> dictionary = dict(zip(key_names, text.split('~')))
>>> dictionary
{'pet': 'cat', 'number': '5', 'color': 'red'}
```